# Swift: data-attr equivalent?

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift

I was wondering if there was a data-attribute equivalent in Swift?

I have a UITableView where each of the cells label is generated from a JSON request. The JSON also contains

```
'id':'123'
```

When the UITableViewCell is clicked I get the label name and pass it to another UIViewController using prepareForSegue.

How can I somehow attach the corresponding JSON ID to the Name provided and assign those to the same Cell so that when the cell is clicked I can get the ID and the Name and pass them both to another view?

Comment: Please add your existing code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use [objc_getAssociatedObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_getAssociatedObject)

To set:

```
import UIKit

var AssociatedObjectHandle: UInt8 = 0

let cell = UITableViewCell(frame: CGRectNull)

objc_setAssociatedObject(cell, &AssociatedObjectHandle, 123, objc_AssociationPolicy(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
```

To retrieve:

```
let value = objc_getAssociatedObject(cell, &AssociatedObjectHandle) as Int
```

This is derived from an example given by an Apple engineer on the Developer Forums: https://devforums.apple.com/message/986325#986325

Answer (score 0):

if the JSON ID is always an integer, you can assign it to the cells view or the label as a tag